# mass mv using find?

Tags: ssh, bash, find, mv

there are a bunch of filename.gif scattered in /home/ directories. I want all the filename.gif replaced by a /home/shared/filename_default.gif.

I tried something like

```
find /home/ -name "filename.gif" | xargs <cmd>
```

but I have no idea to reference what I want to. Wasnt sure to ask this here or stackoverflow

Edit:
This works exactly like I explained it, except I not only wanted the data from filename_default to replace filename.gif, but also for filename.gif to be renamed filename_default.gif. So I did `mv {} filename_default.gif` and mv'ed all the files from their directories to /root/ under the name filename_default.gif ... lol. is there anyway to reference the changing variable in a directory..

for example find /home/ -name "filename.gif"  was actually located like this...

```
/home/brian/dir/1/2/3/filename.gif
/home/beth/dir/1/2/3/filename.gif
/home/andrea/dir/1/2/3/filename.gif
```

How can I reference brian, beth, andrea... like a wildcard *.

```
cp /home/shared/filename_default.gif /home/*/dir/1/2/3/filename_default.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`find /home/ -name filename.gif -exec mv -f /home/shared/filename_default.gif {} \;`

The -exec flag has find execute a command on every found object.  The `{}` indicates the name of the found file.  You then have to terminate the shell command with `\;`.  You could arguably use `ln -s` to symlink those .gifs.  That might be easier if you ever want to change your shared .gif without redoing this sort of find and move.

*EDIT* Good points by  Denilson below.  Despite the question involving `mv`, it'll only work once, before the source file is gone.  (moved)  His advice on the echo command is a good way to double check what's going to happen, before it does.

`find /home/ -name filename.gif -exec cp -p /home/shared/filename_default.gif {} \;`



--Christopher Karel

Comment: You should use `cp` instead of `mv`. Also, adding `echo` before the command would be a nice test before the actual run.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home -name filename.gif -type f -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0 --max-args 1 cp -l  /home/shared/filename_default.gif
```

This isn't the wildcard you asked for, but it does accomplish the first part of your task, namely putting "`filename_default.gif`" in the target directories.  If that works the way you want, you can then replace the '`cp -l /home/shared/filename_default.gif`' portion of the command with '`rm`', and replace '`-printf "%h\0"`' with '`-print0`' to remove the original file.

This presumes you want to take the contents of `/home/shared/filename_default.gif` and put those contents in a file named '`filename_default.gif`' in all of the directories that contain '`filename.gif`', removing '`filename.gif`' (and thus effectively replacing '`filename.gif`' named files with an identical image in a file named '`filename_default.gif`')

If you want to replace '`filename.gif`' but leave the name the same, then replace '`-printf "%h\0"`' with '`-print0`' and omit the `rm` step.

Answer (score 0):

`# find -type f -name 'filename.gif' -exec cp -v /home/shared/filename_default.gif {} \;`

This will replace all your "filename.gif" files with the contents of "filename_default.gif"
but won't rename "filename.gif" to "filename_default.gif"

To rename use following command

`# rename 's/filename.gif/filename_default.gif/' $(find -type f -name 'filename.gif')`

HTH

Comment: Don't parse `$(find ...)`, this will fail if a file name contains a space. Use `-exec` the second time as well: `find -type f -name 'filename.gif' -exec rename 's/filename.gif/filename_default.gif/' {} +`. Also, note that this is using the `rename` provided by Debian and Ubuntu, which comes from the Perl examples package; there are different `rename` commands floating around.

Comment: @Gilles - Thanks for the clarifications. I will remember your comments about `find`. Also I didn't know that `rename` is available only on Debian/Ubuntu. Thanks for that too. :)

Comment: @Gilles - What can be the possible on-liner solution for this problem?